# How to implement type ahead functionality for UIsearchbar in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have to implement the type ahead functionality for a search bar in ipad. whether such functionality is by default provided by any search bar delegate or how to implement it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know this functionality is not provided by default, and you should do it by yourself. If you use tableView to display search results you should override `searchBar:textDidChange:` method of UISearchBar delegate. Something like this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self setSearchString:searchText];
    [self.searchResultsTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: How to reload data in the table depending on the search string?

Comment: Your searchResultsTable has dataSource. This data source implements methods like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` & `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` etc. in implementation of this methods you ask your database (or whatever source of data you use) to return results according to `searchText` & every time you change searchText (aka enter new letters in search bar) results are different, so when you call reloadData tableView is filled with new data.

Comment: @Tweety : once you got the string form your own array of possible search results and call [yourTableView reloadData].